# Focus on bootstrap textarea with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble focusing on a textarea on a webpage which uses jquery and bootstrap. It should be a trivial job but I don't see why it doesn't work the way it it supposed to.

```
$('#textarea').focus();
```

By default, bootstrap gives a blue glow to a focused area (see http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html?#forms). Unfortunately, the line above doesn't seem to do the job.

To be more specific, I have a button which opens displays a side-pane with an editor (textarea). My aim is to automatically send the focus to the textarea after displaying the pane.

Comment: So is the problem that `.focus()` doesn't focus, or that it does focus and the blue glow is missing? The glow is simply css based on the `:focus` selector, so if you focus the element successfully the glow should come with it...

Comment: Sorry, but I can't reproduce. This works as intended, glow with bootstrap, like @KP wrote.

Comment: Can you provide the code (including the code to display the side pane) in a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested `$("#input01").focus();` on the [bootstrap page you referenced](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html?#forms). Works fine to focus the input with id `input01`, which turn blue. So this says to me focusing on an input element that is styled by bootstrap works fine. In fact the blue glow you see is just based on the css `:focus` selector in bootstrap's styles, so as long as you correctly select the element the styles should work fine.

My guess is your `focus()` call is either using the wrong jQuery selector, or is perhaps running out of sync with what else is going on on the page, such as the showing of the side-pane. Make sure the `#textarea` element exists before selecting it.

If you post more specific code I could help you with more specific answers.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. I managed to fix my own problem. It turned out to be a timing issue. I was showing the dialogue with fadeIn and focusing without waiting for the fade to pass. If I bind the focus on a showed event, things work smooth.

Comment: @AtanasAtanasov - If you answered your own question, you should post that as an answer and not just accept the first answerer's response as the correct answer, adding a comment.  A +1 would be appropriate if you found it useful.  Otherwise, future users coming here will have to dig through comments to figure out a solution.

Comment: @merv I agree with you in principle, however if you notice I suggested his call to `focus()` was out of sync with the DOM manipulation, and this was exactly the issue so marking my answer as the solution isn't out of place. That concept alone should help others to troubleshoot similar symptoms.